# Is there a way to parse a multi-part post request values and save them to a value object without tons of loops/ifs?

Tags: java, file-upload

I have a multi-part post form that requires users to enter some basic info into the text field. Users have option to either upload a video file or enter a youtube link.

I got the upload part to work, I am using ServletFileUpload to save the file to the server, then upload that to S3. I'm having trouble with how to get the values from the textfields of the form without going through many loops and checking the field names trying to match them with the fields of the value object.

Example:

Suppose I have entity file:

```
public class Video {
 private String name;
 private String url;
 private String description;
 private Video() {}

 public Video(String, String, String) {
  this.field = value; ...
 }
}
```

And the form is something like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="/member/uploadVideo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="name" type='text'/>
<input name="file" type='file'/>
<input name="url" type='text'/>
<input name="description" type='text'/>
</form>
```

In the backend, I'm doing something like this:

```
 for (Object item : items) {
        fileItem = (FileItem) item;
        if (fileItem.isFormField()) {
            logger.info(fileItem.getName() +  " : " + fileItem.getString());
        } else if (!fileItem.isFormField() && (fileItem.getName() != null && !fileItem.getName().isEmpty())) {
            uploadedFile = fileItem;
        }
    }
```

How can I easily get the textfield values and create a new Video() without looping through and doing ifs to see if the field name is matching the fields of Video()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, not the best way, is to save the form field values to a hashmap, then later use a method to reconstruct the value object using that hashmap.